# Is there enough evidence that this USB-C power bank works with my laptop as per the specification and not harming my laptop?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, usb-c

I recently purchased a HP ProBook 440 14 inch G9 Notebook PC. According to the specifications, user manual, and user guide that came with the unit, as well as the USB-C power connector port symbol on the unit, I should be able to charge the unit via the USB-C port using the appropriate source.

I also purchased a B653 Choetech PD45W 20,000mAh Power Bank with 45W Power Delivery that I intend to use for charging my laptop when the standard power supply is unavailable.

After comparing the specifications of both units in detail, my conclusion is that they are compatible and should not harm my laptop. However, I would like a second opinion to confirm that the specification on my laptop input power matches the power bank output power and I am not missing any information. Here are the specifications:

> The computer can operate on DC power within one or more of the following specifications. The voltage and current for your computer are located on the regulatory label.
>
> Table 12-1 DC power specifications:
>
> Input Power Rating Operating voltage and current
>
> - 5 V dc @ 2 A / 12 V dc @ 3 A /15 V dc @ 3 A – 45 W USB-C®
> - 5 V dc @ 3 A / 9 V dc @ 3 A / 12 V dc @ 3.75 A /15 V dc @ 3 A – 45W USB-C
>   …
> - 19.5 V dc @ 3.33 A – 65 W

The laptop’s standard AC adapter has an input of 100-240 V~1.7 A and an output of 19.5 V@3.33A 65W.
The power bank’s specifications are as follows:

> Input/Entrée:
>
> - 20000mAh (74 Wh)
> - USB-C 5.0V=3.0A, 9.0V=3.0A, 12.0V=3.0A, 15.0V=3.0A, 20.0V=2.25A (45.0W Max)
> - USB-C 5,0V=3,0A, 9,0V=3,0A, 12,0V=3,0A, 15.0V=3,0A, 20,0V=2.25A (45,0W Max)
>
> Output/ Sortie:
>
> - Table 1:
> - USB-C 5.0V=30A, 9.0V=3.0A, 12.0V=3.0A, 15.0V=3.0A, 20.0V=2.25A (45.0W Max)
> - USB-C 5,0V=3,0A, 9,0V=3.0A, 12,0V=3.0A 15,0V=3,0A, 20,0V=2,25A (45,0W Max) 
>   Table 2:

As you can see, the second line of the laptop’s DC input power matches the first line of the power bank’s output specification, therefore as per the specification and technical requirement aspects, the power bank should be able to provide power to the laptop with no harm to the power board and battery.

Could you please confirm if my statement is correct? Please feel free to comment if I am missing any information here. Thank you.

Comment: It should work but you need to contact HP for confirmation

Comment: “However, I would like a second opinion to confirm that this setup will work 100% and that there is no risk involved.” The B653 Choetech PD45W should work. At worst it won’t charge. It will not blow up the device or the laptop.

Comment: Thank you John. I did  that when I haven't had my investigation yet. The first tier of support I talked to was not tech savvy and she referenced the standard power supply with 65W PD and suggested that I should use 65W power bank. I did not inquire if there is a 2nd level of support that I can talk to to get more detail. As per your suggestion, now that I have more information, it might be the the right time to inquire if there is a 2nd line of support to discuss this with.

Comment: Thank you Giacomo, Yes, that is my intention. I would like to know if there is even a minimal risk to damage power sources in the laptop or the battery connecting it to this power bank.

Comment: @Faramarz There is no risk. Why did you buy it if you think there is a risk? The voltage, amperage and wattage match up. You should be fine. What other answer do you need?

Comment: I needed comments and confirmation like yours Giacomo. I am not an Electronic engineer and I just want to make sure I am not missing any details. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

USB-C devices have a [number of ways to communicate](https://hackaday.com/2023/01/04/all-about-usb-c-resistors-and-emarkers/) the purpose of the device, and voltage and current specifications, such as simple pull-down and pull-up resistors, and "emarkers", i.e., ID chips which communicate using USB PD protocol. Manufacturers are loathe to make these specification known, since they'd *much* prefer you buy the OEM parts. HP in particular, has made efforts [to shut down printers for using non-OEM supplies](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2024/01/hp-sued-again-for-blocking-third-party-ink-from-printers-accused-of-monopoly/)!

If a reputable power supply/bank manufacturer indicates their device *should* work on that PC, it *probably* is fine to try. However, this site tries to provide specific answers, or at least a source for finding answers rather than "professional opinion". Unless someone has *used* that device with that specific model PC, the question is hard to answer.

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely right. There is a range of different voltages, amperage .. on both the laptop and power bank specifications which I only mentioned a few related one here and based on the protocols you mentioned, the laptop and power source can communicate within that range. What I meant to ask here and I may have not done a good job, is,  from technical aspect, scientifically, the specification matches 100%  and it should work. I will go ahead an edit my original question. Thanks for brining up the point.